# Nested DIVs and Height

Tags: html, css

So I am breaking this page into several blocks that have a bunch of checkbox options. The goal is 4 tiles wide 3 tiles tall.  The problem is that I set the "columns" to be 100% height which I thought would be 100% of the parent div, but it seems that it is actually 100% of the the parents parent, any ideas?

```
<div id="left" style="width:50%;height:100%;display:inline;float:left">
    <div id="leftRow1" style="width:100%;height:30%;display:inline;text-align:center">
        <div id="column1" style="width:50%;height:100%;display:inline;text-align:left;float:left">
            <h3>Appliances</h3>
            <div>
                <input id="dishwasher" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox">Dishwasher
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="dryer" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox">Dryer
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="freezer" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox">Freezer
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="garbage" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox">Garbage
            </div>

        </div>
        <div id="column2" style="width:50%;height:100%;display:inline;text-align:left;float:right">
            <h3 style="color:white">.</h3>
            <div>
                <input id="microwave" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox">Microwave
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="range" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox">Range/Oven
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="refridgerator" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox">Refridgerator
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="washer" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox">Washer
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="leftRow2" style="width:100%;height:30%;display:inline;text-align:center">
        <div id="column3" style="width:50%;height:100%;display:inline;text-align:left;float:left">
            <h3>Basement</h3>
            <div>
                <input id="finished" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox">Finished
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="partialfinish" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox">Partially Finished
            </div>

        </div>
        <div id="column4" style="width:50%;height:100%;display:inline;text-align:left;float:right">
            <h3 style="color:white">.</h3>
            <div>
                <input id="unfininshed" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox">Unfinished
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="none" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox">No Basement
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should avoid using inline styles because it makes your code unruly to manage and read.

Comment: how does this help solve my problem?

Comment: I does not necessarily solve your problem, but it make it *significantly* easier to edit the CSS in your code. It also helps prevent problems down the road by increasing readability (and therefore reducing the chance of creating typos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with `display: inline`. I didn't notice that at first with all the inline styling. You can't set the height on elements set to display inline. If you change them to `inline-block` then it should work fine.

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tFJJd/1/)

Also, I took the liberty of removing your inline styling and moving them to 3 classes: wrapper - outermost div, leftrow - your two main divs (appliances and basement) and column - all inside divs.

[Fixed Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tFJJd/2/)

Comment: I tried this, nothing changed.  When I looked at your demo page, it was not working either.  when I removed that from the css section, the content actually appeared as expected.. however the live model doesn't display that way, the columns are set to 100% height which are inside a row which is set to 30% height, the thoughts were the column would be 100% of the row

Comment: Sorry about that, I was completely looking at the wrong thing the first time. I updated my answer.

Comment: thanks, it s working now, those damn inline and inline-block differences